# not getting the correct sum - openmp

Tags: c, openmp

When I run this code I am getting `2542199.979500` as the answer. However, the correct answer is `1271099.989750`. Could someone please tell me where the error is?

This is the code which contains the bug:

```
#include <omp.h>
#define N 1000

main ()
{
    int i, nthreads;
    int chunk = 10;
    float a[N], b[N], c[N], d[N];
    double result;
    #pragma omp parallel 
    {
        nthreads = omp_get_num_threads();
        printf("no of threads %d", nthreads);     
        #pragma for shared(a,b,c,d,result) private(i) schedule(static,chunk)
        for (i=0; i < N; i++){
            a[i] = i * 1.5;
            b[i] = i + 22.35;
        }   
        #pragma for shared(a,b,c,d,result) private(i) schedule(static,chunk)
        for(i=0; i < N; i++){
            result = result + (a[i]+b[i]);
        }
    }
    printf("value is %f", result);
}
```

Furthermore, when the number of threads is 3 I get
`3813299.969250`

The result depends on the number of threads used. Could this be a bug in openmp, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Can you tell us the intention of your code? I mean why do you expect the output that you expect?

Comment: i did the same thing without openmp and got 1271099.989750

Comment: See, now how would you guess which one is correct? My question was what does your code do? Something like " My code sorts N numbers", "My code adds numbers from 1 to N". Likewise what does your code do?

Comment: it takes the addition of all elements in both arrays, my gosh cant you see it?

Comment: I don't follow the syntax of your pragmas.  I thought they needed to start with "#pragma omp".  It would seem that either you have a different version than I do, or you are ignoring warning messages that you shouldn't be ignoring.

Comment: @user602774 I can see that two arrays are being added. But I dont know what your magic numbers `1.5`, `22.35` are? I dont prefer solving a problem just for the heck of it without knowing what is the purpose of it. I'm more interested in understanding what the problem statement is than simply point out some errors in code

Comment: @PavanManjunath ok shall i tell you, those values are the radio frequency and amplitude of some rocket engine control unit.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest at least the following two changes...

for the declaration of `result`...

```
// result should be initialized
double result = 0;
```

For your final pragma...

```
// specify the "reduction"
#pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:result)
```

Without specifying the "reduction", the summation to `result` is invalid since `result` would be modified independently in each thread -- resulting in a race condition.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenMP#Reduction

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <omp.h>
#define N 1000

int main ()
{

int i, nthreads;
int chunk = 10;
float a[N], b[N], c[N], d[N];
double result=0;

#pragma omp parallel
nthreads = omp_get_num_threads();
printf("no of threads %d\n", nthreads);

#pragma omp parallel for
for (i=0; i < N; i++){
  a[i] = i * 1.5;
  b[i] = i + 22.35;
}

#pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:result)
for(i=0; i < N; i++){
result = result + (a[i]+b[i]);
}

printf("value is %f", result);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: One more thing: you probably want to get rid of the initial `#pragma omp parallel`.  I suspect that it does not do what you want it to do.

Comment: i did all what you said but still it gives me the wrong answer :(

Answer (score 1):

Please see comments inline.

```
// openmp.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <omp.h>

#define N 1000

// main should return a int
int main(){
    int i, nthreads;
    float a[N], b[N];
    // give result a initial value !
    double result = 0;

#pragma omp parallel
{
    nthreads = omp_get_num_threads();
    // just print numthreads ONCE
#pragma omp single
    printf("no. of threads %d\n", nthreads);

#pragma omp for
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        a[i] = i *1.5;
        b[i] = i + 22.35;
    }

#pragma omp for
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        double sum = a[i] + b[i];
// atomic operation needed !
#pragma omp atomic
        result += sum;
    }

#pragma omp single
    printf("result = %f\n", result);
}
    return 0;
}
```

Compile using `cc -fopenmp -std=gnu99 openmp.c`, the output is:

```
no. of threads 4
result = 1271099.989750
```

Comment: Are the `#pragma omp single` lines really necessary?  Aren't those lines already in a single-threaded context?  Also, is `#pragma single` an error since it doesn't include "omp".

Comment: Also, I would suggest that `#pragma omp for` may not actually be using multiple threads.  Try it with `#pragma omp parallel for`.

Comment: Not to nitpick, but you changed the operation used to calculate `b[i]`.  As a result, the program as given does not produce the result that you stated.

Comment: @nobar-Thanks very much for your suggestion. I've modified the code accordingly. Since the two `for` loops are in `#pragma omp parallel`, so `#pragma omp parallel for` is not necessary, `#pragma omp for` will be suffice. Same reason for the `#pragma omp single`. 
As for the `b[i]=a[i]+22.35`, it's a typo - I didn't cut-copy but re type the code.

Comment: One other note: My compiler (gcc) doesn't like `#pragma single` without the "omp".  I don't know if yours is different, but this article may give some insight: http://www.viva64.com/en/d/0028/

Comment: @nobar- Oh, another typo, again. Poor me. Thanks for pointing them out, really helpful. And yes, `#pragma single` is not acceptable on my compiler.

Comment: @JinghaoShi How come your code works and mine does not. The only difference is i have specified shared(a,b,c,d,result) private(i) schedule(static,chunk) in omp for's

Comment: @user602774: `private(i)` is the evil, I guess. If `i` is private, then every thread will go from 0 to N, which contradicts your intention that distribute 0~N to each threads.

Comment: @user602774: The difference is the `atomic` pragma in the second for loop. In your original code you were not updating the result atomically, so the final value was not computed correctly.

Comment: @Jinghao Shi: No, private is not the reason here. OpenMP makes the loop variable of a for private implicitly, even if you don't specify `private(i)`.

Comment: @user602774: Another difference is that your `#pragma for` lines are not valid (according to my compiler).  If you simply comment out those two lines, your program still does not work.  You have to specify the pragmas correctly or they will be ignored, and the way this code is structured, you *must* have `#pragma omp for` around the second loop.

Answer (score 0):

In openMP one should try to minimise the parallel regions, in this case one is possible and hence enough. Here is a simple C++ version doing just that.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <omp.h>

const int N=1000;

int main ()
{
  const double A = 22.35;
  const double B = 1.5;

  double a[N], b[N], c[N], d[N];
  double result=0;

#pragma omp parallel
  { // begin parallel region
#pragma omp master
    std::cout << "no of threads: " << omp_get_num_threads() << std::endl;

    // this loop and the following could be merged and the arrays avoided.
#pragma omp for
    for(int i=0; i<N; ++i) {
      a[i] = i * B;
      b[i] = i + A;
    }
#pragma omp for reduction(+:result)
    for(int i=0; i<N; ++i)
      result += a[i]+b[i];
  } // end parallel region

  double answer = N*(A+0.5*(B+1)*(N-1));

  std::cout << "computed result = " << std::setprecision(16) << result
            << '\n'
            << "correct answer  = " << std::setprecision(16) << answer
            << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

I get (using gcc 4.6.2 on Mac OS X 10.6.8):

```
no of threads: 2
computed result = 1271099.999999993
correct answer  = 1271100
```